# Переключение фокуса на элемент управления после выбора вкладки

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, tabcontrol

Есть `TabControl`. Чтобы нельзя было выбирать вкладки через клик, а можно было бы только программно, я присвоил всем вкладкам `IsEnabled="False` и переписал стили для `Label` чтобы не было серого цвета шрифта при `IsEnabled="False`.

Далее я хочу, чтобы когда на `TabItem` лежит, к примеру, `TextBox`, он получал фокус сразу после вызова `MyTabItem.Selected = true`. Но этого не происходит. Установка для всех `TabItem` и моего `TabControl` свойств (через стили в `App.xaml`) `Focusable="False"` и `IsTabStop="False"` не помогает.

Comment: В чем суть вопроса-то? При смене таба передать фокус вложенному элементу?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да. Если что, таб меняется только программным путём через метод `SelectTab`.

Comment: Кстати, чтобы вкладки нельзя было выбирать вручную – установите им значение `IsEnabled="False"`, ваш метод несколько костылен. Использовать наследование для таких простых случаев в WPF не комильфо.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Согласен насчёт костыльности решения. Но установка `IsEnabled="False"` делает все надписи на вкладках почему-то серыми и я не знаю как это убрать.

Comment: *все надписи на вкладках почему-то серыми* - ну это вас не должно волновать, т.к. отображаться должна именно та вкладка, которая нужна в данный момент (она будет IsEnabled=True)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Мне надо чтобы вкладки отображались одинаково — без серых цветов.

Comment: Ну это как раз-таки не сложно, нужно отредактировать стандартный стиль, в нем есть триггеры на IsEnabled=false, вот из триггера надо убрать эту строчку: `<Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>`

Comment: Я предлагаю вам отредактировать вопрос и удалить из него всё не относящееся к делу: стили, код класса — они не нужны

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо, что помогли отрефакторить существующее решение. Я уже применил в коде ваш совет. К сожаленью, мне это не помогло в решение существующей проблемы и пришлось тащить кучу стилей для `Label`.

Comment: Не понял про кучу стилей Label, просто щелкните в дизайнере Visual Studio правой по TabItem и выберите "Edit Template" - "Edit a Copy...", студия добавит стандартный шаблон элемента, который можно отредактировать (я удалил 4 триггера на `IsEnabled=false` из него)

Comment: @АндрейNOP А я не знаю про такие функции, поэтому в интернете пришлось искать заготовки и по ним собрал велосипед:) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня сработало такое:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (TabItem)myTabControl.SelectedItem;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
    {
        selectedItem.Focus();
        selectedItem.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }));
}
```

Т.е. мы ставим задачу на установку фокуса в очередь, она должна выполниться только после того, как `TabControl` реально переключит текущую вкладку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С использованием наследования:

```
class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        var selectedItem = (TabItem)SelectedItem;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
        {
            selectedItem.Focus();
            selectedItem.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: А если мне хочется это поведение для всех `TabControl` в приложении, то наследования не избежать? При этом надо чтобы это поведение выполнялось не какой-то определённый клик (тогда уже проще вручную прописать `Focus` для каждого случая), а после установки *произвольной вкладки* `MyTabItem.Selected = true`

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, получается – да, либо через наследование, либо через поведение (behavior)

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, написать как это будет через наследование, так как мои попытки работы с `TraversalRequest` не увенчались успехом?

Comment: Да вроде всё также, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Выделение в WPF устанавливается при помощи класса [`FocusManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx). В XAML фокус можно определить с помощью прикреплённого свойства `FocusManager.FocusedElement`, правда это будет срабатывать один раз, поэтому для управления фокусом при смене вкладки придётся писать код.

Comment: Неплохо бы показать рабочий пример с использованием этого класса.

Comment: А есть универсальное решение для переиспользования в разных TabControl и TabItem?